# Error fetching feature types when adding WFS to ArcMap using Interoperability Extension

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, wfs, data-interoperability

I'm trying to add a WFS layer to ArcMap using the Interoperability Extension. I get the following error when clicking the '...' next to the 'Feature Types' option.

[image: Fetching feature types error]

I'm unable to add the data because of this.

Any ideas on what could cause this error? As far as I know the Data Interoperability extension and license are correctly installed and activated. The WFS link should be correct. I tried other URLs of different WFS layers and they all give the same error.

Comment: I see that the service supports [WFS 2.0.0 by default](http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/kadastralekaartv2/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&) and that format isn't yet supported by the Data Interoperability extension.  Just wondering whether (even though you specified version 1.1.0) the WFS GetFeature requests are sent with the wrong version specified.  Can you check using Fiddler?

Comment: I loaded this WFS correctly into QGIS, so the service seems to be working correctly.